# KendoUI Angular Grid auto expansion of kendoGridDetailTemplate not working in latest kendoUI

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid, kendo-angular-ui

I was previously working with Angular-9/Node-12/KendoAngularGrid-4.8.0 and the expansion of kendoGridDetailTemplate was working fine.

After upgrading to Angular-15/Node-16/KendoAngularGrid-7.4.2, it is no longer working.

Here are some details:

Grid HTML:

```
<kendo-grid
        [data]="displayedData"
        [selectable]="{ checkboxOnly: false, mode: 'single' }"
        (selectionChange)="selectionChangeHandler($event)"
        [columnMenu]="{filter: false, sort: false, columnChooser: { expanded: true }}"
        ...
        [kendoGridExpandDetailsBy]="expandDetailsBy"
        [expandedDetailKeys]="expandedDetailKeys"
        [kendoGridSelectBy]="'id'"
        [selectedKeys]="selectedKeys">
```

ExpandDetailsBy:

```
public expandDetailsBy = (dataItem: any): any => {
    return dataItem.id;
};
```

There's a modal, which when closed, will update the expandedDetailKeys and selectedKeys:

```
public closeModal(toExpandId: string): void {
     this.expandedDetailKeys.push(toExpandId);
     this.selectedKeys.push(toExpandId);
}
```

displayedData is a list of dataItems where a dataItem is:

```
{
    id: "abcdef123",
    name: "some name",
    ...
}
```